# Access query returning dates out of range input

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have constructed a query to select all dates between a date range which is inputted by the user. 
When the user selects the date before todays date, the current date or a day after the current date it brings back dates not within the date range.

Please see my examples below:

Before todays date returning incorrect dates in range:

[image: before todays date returning incorrect dates in range]

Selecting date 3 days after current date query query perfectly:

[image: selecting date 3 days after current date query query perfectly]

```
 Option Compare Database

  Private Sub Command121_Click()

  Dim strCriteria, task As String



strCriteria = "([PromisedDeliveryDate] >= #" & Me.DateFrom & "# And [PromisedDeliveryDate] <= #" & Me.DateTo & "#)"
task = "select * from SageOrderLine_Live where (" & strCriteria & ")"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** How would I add to query by the `customeraccountnumber` as well? I have tried to add it on but it's bringing up an error:

```
  DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
"select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] >= " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] <= " & Format(Me.DateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[CustomerAccountNumber] = " & Me.CustomerAccount & ""
```

The "Enter parameter box" is appearing when selecting search:

[image: Enter parameter box appearing when selecting search]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing date values within a SQL statement, you will need to ensure that such dates adhere to the expected format of:

```
#mm/dd/yyyy#
```

Else, a date such as `08/11/2019` (8<sup>th</sup> November 2019) will be interpreted within the SQL as `11/08/2019` (11<sup>th</sup> August 2019), yielding the results that you are witnessing.

You can achieve this using the [`Format`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) function:

```
Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

Here, the additional backslashes `\` preceding the octothorpes & forward slashes act as [Escape Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), forcing MS Access to display the next character as a literal.

For example:

```
?Format(Date(), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
#11/09/2019#
```

In your code, this might be written:

```
Private Sub Command121_Click()
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
    "select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
    "[PromisedDeliveryDate] >= " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
    "[PromisedDeliveryDate] <= " & Format(Me.DateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could reference the form controls directly within the SQL statement, in which case, no formatting is required:

```
Private Sub Command121_Click()
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
    "select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
    "[PromisedDeliveryDate] >= [Forms]![YourFormName]!DateFrom and " & _
    "[PromisedDeliveryDate] <= [Forms]![YourFormName]!DateTo "
End Sub
```

(Updating `YourFormName` to the name of your form, of course).

---

**EDIT:** If you wish to add the `CustomerAccountNumber` to the filter, since this is a text field, you'll need to enclose the value with either single or double quotes, e.g. using single quotes:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
"select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] >= " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] <= " & Format(Me.DateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[CustomerAccountNumber] = '" & Me.CustomerAccount & "'"
```

Or double-quotes:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
"select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] >= " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[PromisedDeliveryDate] <= " & Format(Me.DateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " and " & _
"[CustomerAccountNumber] = """ & Me.CustomerAccount & """"
```

Comment: I know i should ask another question, but how would i add to query by the customeraccountnumber as well? I have tried to add it one but bringing up an error

Comment: You're welcome! It depends on the data type of the `customeraccountnumber` field - if this is a text field, then you'll need to enclose the value with single or double quotes; if a numerical field, no quotes are required.

Comment: Please see my edit at the bottom of the question. Thats what I have at the moment, however its coming from a combo box

Comment: Two questions: (1) is `CustomerAccountNumber` a text field or numerical field? (2) Is the bound column of your `Me.CustomerAccount` combobox the `CustomerAccountNumber` field?

Comment: (1) It is a text field, sorry i didnt answer that first time (2) yes the bound column is the CustomerAccountNumber. I have it working however a parameter box appears when running the search and you have to enter in the Customer account number and then the records appear. Not sure what im doing wrong. See my picture i uploaded in question